# How can I extract the month using sqldf package

Tags: r, sqldf

I tried to get a view that is based on group by of date by using sqldf package and a month function but I got an error :`Error in sqliteSendQuery(con, statement, bind.data) :   error in statement: no such function: month`

Here is my query: `s<-sqldf("select month(dateTime),sum(wolfs) group by dateTime")`

Attached is a toy data frame:

```
 df <- read.table(text = "dateTime         birds    wolfs     snakes
                         2014-05-21        9         7    a
                         2014-04-28        8         4    b
                         2014-04-13        2         8    c
                         2014-03-12        2         3    a
                         2014-02-04        8         3    a
                         2014-02-29        1         2    a
                         2014-01-17        7         1    b
                         2014-01-16        1         5    c
                         2014-09-20        9         7    c
                         2014-08-21        8         7    c ",header = TRUE)
```

How can I extract the month using sqldf package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you are used to SQL Server, but the `sqldf` backend being used in your case is SQLite, where there is no `MONTH` function. Try this instead:

```
R> sqldf("SELECT strftime('%m', dateTime) AS Month
            ,SUM(wolfs) AS Wolves
         FROM df
         GROUP BY strftime('%m', dateTime)")
#    Month Wolves
#  1    01      6
#  2    02      5
#  3    03      3
#  4    04     12
#  5    05      7
#  6    08      7
#  7    09      7
```

---

Comment: You could just write `GROUP BY Month` to avoid repetition